# Chart showing a comparison after checking a checkbox

Tags: checkbox, looker-studio

I'm trying to figure out how to connect checkbox with chart.

What I need to do is the following:
I have a chart showing two lines (two sets of data, lets name them A and B).
After checking a checkbox "compare A with previous period" or "compare B with previous period" those data disappear and instead of them a suitable comparison is shown.

I know that it is possible to make checkbox dependent chart like here:
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/23a0d8ac-96c0-42cc-a991-5a21bc7c9962/page/VvbsB?s=rw4uzVA5G9Y
but I don't know how to do it.

I tried looking for the solution on the Internet, but nothing found.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step introduction how to blend data and add checkboxes to show/hide graphs. Also how to do a calculation across datafields in different datasets, which were blended.

Add to the dataset a checkbox with the name `compare_a_with_previous_period` the field `3days average on/off` with

```
case when compare_a_with_previous_period then 3days average else null end
```

Depending on the checkbox data is shown in that field or not (null). For blending/joining the data over different dates, a timeshift has to be done. Therefore, create a field `date_old` with

```
datetime_add(Date,interval 30 day)
```

Create an parameter `show_differences` with range 0 to 1 and add a field `show_differences` with

```
case when show_differences = 0 then 0 else 1 end
```

This will later be used to switch on/off the graph for the difference calculation.

Blend the data with itself using `date` and `date_old` as join and range. And rename the `3 day average` to `3 days_old`

[image]

Add the chart and click on the "add metric"
[image]
and enter

```
case when show_differences > 0 then 3days average - 3days_old else null end
```

to do a calculation between the bend datasets. Under Style set the missing data to "Line Breaks".

Comment: Hi Samuel, thank you for your answer. 
To let you better understand my question I prepared test report you can edit to present your solution.
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3eca0fdc-9439-4133-88d4-3aaf2ca81394

As I said before the intended working is that after checking a checkbox the data shown on the diagram disappears are and replaced with comparison of "No results rate" metric with previous period

The data set is the following:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1olIFoo2pAqsITMJ8Onau8nDo7i--lc5cAg2oFEakSxE/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Wojciech: See your dataset

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! My question is if your method makes comparison of any period (lets say 17 days with previous 17 days, 76 days with previous 76 days or anything) possible?

Comment: @Wojciech yes, you can write any day number in `date_add` formula. In the user should define  the time difference, do following steps: First generate a parameter `time_diff ` with the type number (I prefer slider, then there are a fixed start and end value  needed). Then modify the formula to `datetime_add(Date,interval time_diff day)`